# What is the sample path of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Assume $\Omega $={head, tail}, let T=$\mathbb N$ and $X_t$ $t\in T$ be a collection of i.i.d random variables following Bernoulli distribution. Since a stochastic process is a function of two variables. When $\omega$ is fixed, we get a sample path, so when fix $\omega$={head}, Is the sample path of $X_t(\omega)$ be the constant 1? But a realization of coin tossing can't be always head . So where is my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that $\Omega=$ {heads,tails}$^T$,
where {heads,tails}$^T$ is the set of all functions from $T$ to {heads,tails}. So a typical $\omega$ is an infinite sequences whose entries are either heads or tails.

Comment: So the space of brownian motion is $\mathbb C(R^+,R)$, I see.

Comment: What does $\Omega=\{heads,tails\}^T$ mean? Thanks!

Comment: @XianjinYang: I edited the question to answer your comment.

Comment: @SergioParreiras How to define a measure on a $\Omega=\{heads, tails\}^T$ if $\omega\in \Omega$ is a function?

Comment: @XianjinYang: if you don't like the word "function", think of it as a "sequence". You can use The Kolmogorov Extension Theorem to define a measures in this space, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem